# import keyboard project from google source code

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am a newer in android. how can i import a project from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/marshmallow-release
to android studio. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to clone the project locally using git

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME
```

Then you check out the specific branch, eg. marchmallow-release. Next example is using SourceTree but you can do it directly with git on the console.

[image]

Finally, open the project in Android Studio